# Bootstrap row fluid spans jump a line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running a query that outputs a span4 element in a row-fluid. I added code in my css to remove the margin-left on the third span4 in a row-fluid. This has also worked so far, but suddenly the one of the span4 jumps a line. Any suggestions why this suddenly stopped working?

You can see the page here:
http://dtm-auto.ch/home/

My css:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:nth-child(3n+1) {
 margin-left: 0!important;
}
```

My code:

```
  <div id="content" class="clearfix row-fluid">
              <div id="main" class="span12 clearfix" role="main">

            <h2 class="text-left">Neue Fahrzeuge</h2> 
                <div class="clearfix row-fluid">
            <?php
              global $wp_query;
   query_posts( array(
  'post_type' => 'acme_product',
'posts_per_page' => 6

)); 
 while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
 $wp_query->the_post();
?><?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?>

                <div id="front-new-video" class="span4"> 
                     <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><h3 id="car-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3> </a>
                    <div class="thumbnail wrapper">
                     <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">Neu</div></div>
                   <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium');?></a>
                    <p>Preis: <span style="color:#FEF158"><?php the_field('preis'); ?> CHF</span></p>
                        <p>Jahr: <span style="color:#FEF158"><?php the_field('jahr'); ?></span></p>
                        <p>Farbe: <span style="color:#FEF158"><?php the_field('farbe'); ?></span></p>
                        <p>KM: <span style="color:#FEF158"><?php the_field('km'); ?> KM</span></p>

                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><h4> <i class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></i> Zum Fahrzeug </h4></a>
                </div>
                </div>
                   <?php 
endwhile; 

?>
              </div>





            </div> <!-- end #main -->
                </div> <!-- end #content -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using `height: 100%` on `#front-new-video` which doesn't really do anything because the parents height(row-fluid) needs to be defiend for `height: 100%` to work.
Use a fixed height or min-height instead and your problem will be solved. e.g `height: 419px;`